# Consumir arquivo json em local com jquery ou javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho um json chamado `product.json` que está na raiz do meu projeto, desejo consumir ele e coloca-lo em uma vitrine na home, porém tentei de diversas formas e não consegui, segue exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "product.json", function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, tente modificando "**$(document).ready(**" para "**$().ready(**"

Depois, substituindo **.get(** por **.ajax(**

```js
$().ready(function(){
    console.log('Start');
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/battles?offset=0&limit=1&sort=recent", 
                success: function(data) {
                         console.log('vai'+data);
                },
                fail: function() {
                         console.log('data');
                }
    });
    console.log('End');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o método `$.get` recebe o JSON em forma de string, e seria preciso parsear o retorno `data` com `JSON.parse(data)`, porém o jQuery possui um método que já faz isso, o [`$.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "product.json", function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Desta forma o valor em `data` será o JSON parseado, de onde você poderá consumir as informações que deseja.